# Python 2.7: decode error output not utf-8 on a simple string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

When I try the following code:

```
a = "C:\Python27\777.xls"
print a
```

I get this error:

`Decode error- output not utf-8`

Although there are other questions which seem related, they mostly seem to be from people actually trying to encode something, whereas I am just trying to make sure my file path does not error out when I call it.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape your slashes:  write `\\` instead of just `\` when you want a backslash.

```
a = "C:\\Python27\\777.xls"
print a
```

Alternatively, you could use a "raw string."  Whenever a string is a raw string, a slash i just a slash, and you don't have to worry about weird stuff happening.

```
a = r"C:\Python27\777.xls"
print a
```

Right now, Python is interpreting the `\777` as a single character, with the octal value `777`, which does not exist.  So Python is puking.  Check out this link to the reference and scroll down a bit for the escape sequences in Python strings. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings

Comment: Works! However just in case someone runs into the problem i wanted to point out that if someone did: a = "C:\Python27\helloworld" print a, it would actually print a statement. Is it just better practice to perhaps 'always' use the backslash?

Comment: Yeah, it's always best practice to use the backslash (PS, this is called "escaping" the backslash).  You can also use what is called a "raw string", and that's just as good.  I'll update my answer to explain a raw string.